# Custom kubernetes cluster logging to Google Cloud Logging

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-logging

I have a custom kuberentes cluster. 
I would like to watch the logs in the Google Cloud Logging. 
I've already read a lot solutions for Elasticsearch but I would prefer the GCL. 
I start read about the FluentD / FluentBit but now I don't know how to start it. 

I couldn't find any documentation for that.  
Where should I start?

**UPDATE**: 
K8S Cluster on Azure and I would like to use the Google Cloud Logging.

**UPDATE**: 
I found the fluentBit OUTPUT plugin named stackdriver. 
The problem now when I use the config below I get an error message.

Config:

```yaml
      outputs: |
        [OUTPUT]
            Name stackdriver
            Match *
            service_account_email {{ .Values.stackdriver.service_account_email }}
            service_account_secret {{ .Values.stackdriver.service_account_secret }}
```

The `helm template .` command shows that its good. 
But when I install the template this is the error:

```bash
    [2023/01/11 13:35:12] [ info] [output:stackdriver:stackdriver.0] metadata_server set to http://metadata.google.internal
    [2023/01/11 13:35:12] [ warn] [output:stackdriver:stackdriver.0] client_email is not defined, using a default one
    [2023/01/11 13:35:12] [ warn] [output:stackdriver:stackdriver.0] private_key is not defined, fetching it from metadata server
    [2023/01/11 13:35:12] [ warn] [net] getaddrinfo(host='metadata.google.internal', err=-2): Name or service not known
    [2023/01/11 13:35:12] [error] [output:stackdriver:stackdriver.0] failed to create metadata connection
    [2023/01/11 13:35:12] [error] [output:stackdriver:stackdriver.0] can't fetch token from the metadata server
    [2023/01/11 13:35:12] [ warn] [output:stackdriver:stackdriver.0] token retrieval failed
    [2023/01/11 13:35:12] [ warn] [net] getaddrinfo(host='metadata.google.internal', err=-2): Name or service not known
    [2023/01/11 13:35:12] [error] [output:stackdriver:stackdriver.0] failed to create metadata connection
    [2023/01/11 13:35:12] [error] [output:stackdriver:stackdriver.0] can't fetch project id from the metadata server
    [2023/01/11 13:35:12] [error] [output] failed to initialize 'stackdriver' plugin
```

Comment: What do you mean by custom cluster, is it on-prem, or managed by GKE?, in case it is by GKE, then by default logs are enabled (as mentioned here https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/management-tools/using-logging-your-apps-running-kubernetes-engine), also you can troubleshoot it following this link (https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-gke-logging)

For on-prem stuff, the only way I am aware of is using anthos https://cloud.google.com/anthos/clusters/docs/on-prem/latest/how-to/application-logging-monitoring

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/buckets#writing this may help as well

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your issue as the information provided is not sufficient.In the meantime please check the documents shared by @KarimTawfik.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. 
I updated the questions!
Our K8s Cluster is in azure and we have to use the Google Cloud Logging.

Comment: I found the bug report btw: 
https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/6691

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in that version: github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/issues/6691